# Check for repeated values in JSON object array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a large JSON file with this structure:

```
[
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd939ab8",
      "serial":"086bd7c39c9a",
      "temp":36.33,
      "x":-0.484375,
      "y":-0.0078125,
      "z":-0.859375,
      "rssi":-70,
      "id":-26648,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.238"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd939ab8",
      "serial":"086bd7c39c94",
      "temp":35.08,
      "x":-0.5078125,
      "y":0.0234375,
      "z":-0.84375,
      "rssi":-87,
      "id":-26633,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.028"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd939ab8",
      "serial":"086bd7c39c94",
      "temp":35.08,
      "x":-0.4921875,
      "y":0.0078125,
      "z":-0.8671875,
      "rssi":-87,
      "id":-26633,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.153"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd939ab8",
      "serial":"086bd7c39c94",
      "temp":35.08,
      "x":-0.4765625,
      "y":0.0234375,
      "z":-0.8671875,
      "rssi":-87,
      "id":-26633,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.278"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd939ab8",
      "serial":"086bd7c39d3b",
      "temp":37.19,
      "x":-0.265625,
      "y":-0.0390625,
      "z":-0.9921875,
      "rssi":-86,
      "id":-30714,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.058"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd9448a0",
      "serial":"086bd7c39d3b",
      "temp":37.19,
      "x":-0.21875,
      "y":0.015625,
      "z":-0.9296875,
      "rssi":-86,
      "id":-30714,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.183"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd9448a0",
      "serial":"086bd7c39d3b",
      "temp":37.19,
      "x":-0.203125,
      "y":0.046875,
      "z":-0.9609375,
      "rssi":-86,
      "id":-30714,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.308"
   }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is sort this file first by `serial` then by `date`, and remove any objects with the same `id` (even if some values change like `sniffer_serial`).

This is what I got so far:

```
import json
from itertools import groupby

#json filepath
json_file_path = "./myfile.json"

#opening and loading the file content
with open(json_file_path, 'r') as j:
     contents = json.loads(j.read())

data = {} #dict that will contain my sorted data

#sorting data
for key, items in groupby(sorted(contents, key = lambda x: (x['serial'], x['date'])), key=lambda x: x['serial']):
     data[key] = list(items)

#saving it as new file
with open('datasorted.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(data))
```

What i'm having trouble with is removing the duplicated objects that have the same `id`. Should I create another dict and iterate to see if already has an entry with the same `id` inside it ?

How I expect the final JSON file to look like:

```
[
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd939ab8",
      "serial":"086bd7c39c94",
      "temp":35.08,
      "x":-0.5078125,
      "y":0.0234375,
      "z":-0.84375,
      "rssi":-87,
      "id":-26633,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.028"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd939ab8",
      "serial":"086bd7c39c9a",
      "temp":36.33,
      "x":-0.484375,
      "y":-0.0078125,
      "z":-0.859375,
      "rssi":-70,
      "id":-26648,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.238"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd939ab8",
      "serial":"086bd7c39d3b",
      "temp":37.19,
      "x":-0.265625,
      "y":-0.0390625,
      "z":-0.9921875,
      "rssi":-86,
      "id":-30714,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.058"
   },
   {
      "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd9448a0",
      "serial":"086bd7c39d3b",
      "temp":37.19,
      "x":-0.21875,
      "y":0.015625,
      "z":-0.9296875,
      "rssi":-86,
      "id":-30714,
      "date":"2021-06-02/09:24:06.183"
   }
]
```

EDIT:

Creating a Pandas dataframe and trying to drop duplicates is raising the following error:

```
KeyError: Index(['id'], dtype='object')
```

Code:

```
dataPandas = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')

dataPandas.drop_duplicates(subset="id",keep="first")
```

Comment: In your `for key, items` loop, `items` is an iterator that contains _all_ the items in that group. If you only care about one of the items, just set that value: `data[key] = list(items)[0]`. Note though that your final `data` will be a `dict`. If you want it to be a list like it was before, do `data = []` and `data.append(list(items)[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues:

1. You want a `list` but you add all the items you care about to a `dict`. Then you write this `dict` to your output json.
2. In your `for key, items` loop, `items` is an iterator that contains *all* the items in that group. If you only care about one of the items (e.g. the first), just set that value like so: `data[key] = list(items)[0]`

Incorporating these changes, you'd get:

```
data = [] #dict that will contain my sorted data

#sorting data
for key, items in groupby(sorted(contents, key = lambda x: (x['serial'], x['date'])), key=lambda x: x['id']):
     data.append(next(items))
```

`next(items)` gets only the next item of the iterator. On the other hand, `list(items)[0]` would convert the *entire* iterator to a list, and then take the first element.

This gives us the following `data`:

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

[
    {
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd939ab8",
        "serial": "086bd7c39c94",
        "temp": 35.08,
        "x": -0.5078125,
        "y": 0.0234375,
        "z": -0.84375,
        "rssi": -87,
        "id": -26633,
        "date": "2021-06-02/09:24:06.028"
    },
    {
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd939ab8",
        "serial": "086bd7c39c9a",
        "temp": 36.33,
        "x": -0.484375,
        "y": -0.0078125,
        "z": -0.859375,
        "rssi": -70,
        "id": -26648,
        "date": "2021-06-02/09:24:06.238"
    },
    {
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd939ab8",
        "serial": "086bd7c39d3b",
        "temp": 37.19,
        "x": -0.265625,
        "y": -0.0390625,
        "z": -0.9921875,
        "rssi": -86,
        "id": -30714,
        "date": "2021-06-02/09:24:06.058"
    }
]
```

---

One potential problem with this: You sort first and then do `groupby`. I'm not sure if this breaks the sort order, but you could always do the `groupby` first and then sort on the `serial`.

```
unique_contents = [next(v) for k, v in groupby(contents, key=lambda x: x['id'])]
data = sorted(unique_contents, key=lambda x: (x['serial'], x['date']))
```

Or in one line, use the generator expression that drove the `unique_contents` list comprehension as the iterator you are sorting:

```
data = sorted(
    (next(v) for k, v in groupby(contents, key=lambda x: x['id'])), 
    key=lambda x: (x['serial'], x['date'])
)
```

---

Also note: you can read and write json directly from the file:

```
#opening and loading the file content
with open(input_file_path, 'r') as j:
     contents = json.load(j)

with open(output_file_path, 'w') as j:
    json.dump(data, indent=4) # indent=4 for pretty-print
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned a lot from this answer, truly.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks solid.

If you don't care about which of the duplicate elements you are using down the line, you can just take the first one:

```py
...
for key, items in groupby(
    sorted(
        contents,
        key=lambda x: (x['serial'], x['date'])
    ),
    key=lambda x: x['serial']
):
    # items is an iterator and if you only care about the first element,
    # you can call next() once on it (instead of converting it to a list),
    # so that it doesn't iterate all entries.
    data[key] = next(items)

# Save as new file with indentation
with open('datasorted.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

The output will look like this:

```
{
    "086bd7c39c94": {
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd939ab8",
        "serial": "086bd7c39c94",
        "temp": 35.08,
        "x": -0.5078125,
        "y": 0.0234375,
        "z": -0.84375,
        "rssi": -87,
        "id": -26633,
        "date": "2021-06-02/09:24:06.028"
    },
    "086bd7c39c9a": {
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd939ab8",
        "serial": "086bd7c39c9a",
        "temp": 36.33,
        "x": -0.484375,
        "y": -0.0078125,
        "z": -0.859375,
        "rssi": -70,
        "id": -26648,
        "date": "2021-06-02/09:24:06.238"
    },
    "086bd7c39d3b": {
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd939ab8",
        "serial": "086bd7c39d3b",
        "temp": 37.19,
        "x": -0.265625,
        "y": -0.0390625,
        "z": -0.9921875,
        "rssi": -86,
        "id": -30714,
        "date": "2021-06-02/09:24:06.058"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is my fault for not making my question clear.
This is a great solution but it's not what I'm looking for, because this only takes the first `serial` it finds to add to the dict. What I want is to have no duplicate `id`'s, preserving the other objects (even with the same serial) so I can later plot this data trought time. If change `key=lambda x: x['serial']` to `key=lambda x: x['id']` it messes with the ordering.

Comment: I edited my question with how the JSON should look like to further clarify thinngs. Thanks for your help

Comment: @LeonardoFelixdaSilva why do you expect `"serial": "086bd7c39c94"` to be sorted _after_ `"serial": "086bd7c39c9a"`? That is the wrong sort order `"086bd7c39c9a" > "086bd7c39c94"` (both lexicographically and if you interpreted it as a hex number)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that happened because I was trying to do 2 things at the same time with not nearly as much attention as I should have given them. I'm sorry for that, I fixed that typo

Comment: I see, in that case, the accepted answer more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to create a DataRame with your dictionary using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` and then running the de-dupe (`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`) functions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further ? I never used pandas before and I got an KeyError when trying to drop duplicates. I edited my question with the code I just tried